# How to replace image element using a json file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, replace, fetch

I am having an issue trying to replace a certain element in my document using "replace". I have created a const titled c, which grabs a specific image using c.replace, but when I run my code, I get an error that states "c.replace is not a function", can anyone provide some guidence on this? here is the code I am using:

```
        function imgenlarger(){
        const t = "test.json"




fetch(t)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (jsonObject) {
    const color = jsonObject['color'];
    for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++ ) {

        let colorTitle = document.createElement('section');
        let colorName = document.createElement('h2');
        colorName.textContent = color[i];
        colorTitle.appendChild(colorName);
        document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').appendChild(colorTitle);
        const c = color[i];
        document.getElementById('bigpic').src = c.replace('90x90', '225x225');
        
    }
  });










        
        }
```

my JSON file:

```
{
    "color":[
        {
            "0": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Flag_Vice_Admiral_of_Red_1805_to_1864.png",
            "1": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Flag_Vice_Admiral_of_Red_1805_to_1864.png",
            "2": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Flag_Vice_Admiral_of_Red_1805_to_1864.png",
            "3": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Flag_Vice_Admiral_of_Red_1805_to_1864.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is `c` a string, or is it something else? `String.prototype.replace()` only exists for a string.

Comment: Can you provide the json content you are using or a portion of it if it's big? The replace function is only for strings, maybe your variable is not a string.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am trying to replace an image with another image in the json file. I made edits to reflect that.

Comment: One thing that does not make sense is you are looping over an array, but only setting the source to one element. So it will only ever be the last index

Comment: `const c = color[i]; console.log(i, c);` Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: I will fix the array and make edits after I get this part working. I want to make sure replacing the image works first.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong. I had to change the json file for it to make more sense, so I re wrote is as:

```
{
    "color":[
        {
            "name": "red",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Flag_Vice_Admiral_of_Red_1805_to_1864.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "blue",
            "image": "https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/2017/05/blue0517.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "yellow",
            "image": "https://professionals.tarkett.com/media/img/M/TH_3917013_3707013_3708013_3912013_3914013_800_800.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "green",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Solid_green.svg/1200px-Solid_green.svg.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

and updated the js file to be:

```
function imgenlarger() {
   const t = "test.json"
   fetch(t)
       .then(function (response) {
           return response.json();
       })
       .then(function (jsonObject) {
           const color = jsonObject['color'];
           for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {

               let colorTitle = document.createElement('section');
               let colorName = document.createElement('h2');
               colorName.textContent = color[i].name;
               colorTitle.appendChild(colorName);
               document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').appendChild(colorTitle);

               var img = document.createElement("img");
               img.src = color[i].image;
               var oldImg = document.getElementById('bigpic');
               document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').replaceChild(img, oldImg);
           }
       });        
   }
```